# Is it possible to only retrieve the latest/last value when using the request.security_lower_tf function in PineScript v5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

So here’s the code that I’m using to retrieve the second timeframes values:

```
secHighArr = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, “1S”, high)
aTable = table.new(position.top_center,2,2)
table.cell(aTable, 1,1, str.tostring(secHighArr))
```

If I’m on a 5 minute timeframe this is obviously returning all the second values in the 5 minute period, is it possible to only retrieve the latest/last secHighArr value instead of all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.security_lower_tf` returns an array. You cannot get only one value out of this call.

```
request.security_lower_tf(symbol, timeframe, expression, ignore_invalid_symbol, currency) → array<type>
```

However, since it is an array, you can get the last value of that array with:

```
len = secHighArr.size()
float last_val = (len > 0) ? array.get(secHighArr, len - 1) : na
```